# Spark scala data frame udf returning rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Say I have an dataframe which contains a column (called colA) which is a seq of row. I want to to append a new field to each record of colA. (And the new filed is associated with the former record, so I have to write an udf.)
How should I write this udf?

I have tried to write a udf, which takes colA as input, and output Seq[Row] where each record contains the new filed. But the problem is the udf cannot return Seq[Row]/ The exception is 'Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported'.
What should I do?

The udf that I wrote:

`val convert = udf[Seq[Row], Seq[Row]](blablabla...)`

And the exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported

Comment: If your final combined row is fixed then create a case class and use that. You will have to give us more information for detailed answer

Comment: What's the input column type? i.e. What's in your "Row"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

since spark 2.0 you can create UDFs which return `Row` / `Seq[Row]`, but you must provide the schema for the return type, e.g. if you work with an Array of Doubles :

```
val schema = ArrayType(DoubleType)

val myUDF = udf((s: Seq[Row]) => {
  s // just pass data without modification
}, schema)
```

But I cant really imagine where this is useful, I would rather return tuples or case classes (or Seq thereof) from the UDFs.

EDIT  :  It could be useful if your row contains more than 22 fields (limit of fields for tuples/case classes)

Comment: Awesome! This is what I need.

And the case is I want the new column to overwrite the origin column using df.withColumn().

And could u please show me the basic usage of case class in spark?

Comment: This is a java udf. What is the correct format for scala?

Comment: @kevinno this is Scala

Comment: How could this answer be used for returning a row in a dataframe that has many columns? Processing rows one at a time can be done as `df1.withColumn(results_col,row_udf(df1.columns)(struct("*")))`, but I am unable to get the returning part working.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, I just wanted to update it according to the new version of Spark.

Since Spark 3.0.0, the method that @Raphael Roth has mentioned is deprecated. Hence, you might get an `AnalysisException`. The reason is that the input closure using this method doesn't have type checking and the behavior might be different from what we expect in SQL when it comes to `null` values.

If you really know what you're doing, you need to set `spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF` configuration to `true`.

Another solution is to use `case class` instead of schema. For example,

```
case class Foo(field1: String, field2: String)

val convertFunction: Seq[Row] => Seq[Foo] = input => {
    input.map {
        x => // do something with x and convert to Foo
    }
}

val myUdf = udf(convertFunction)
```