# UDF with Dynamic Data Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write the udf that can remove few keys from Map. But the Map's key and value type is not fixed, it can be String or Array or something else. How should I define such udf. I am using Spark version 2.4.4.

Below is my udf for Map[String, string]:

```
val mapKeys = //Seq[String]
val mapFilterUdf = udf[Map[String, String], Map[String, String]] {
    map => map.filter{case (key, _) => mapKeys.contains(key)}
}
mapFilterUdf(dataFrame.col("column_name")).as(column.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Any` in your UDF only if you provide the runtime-schema of your column as a second argument to `udf`:

```
val mapKeys : Seq[Any] = Seq("k1")

val df = Seq(
    Map("k1" -> "v1","k2" -> "v2")
).toDF("map")

val colSchema = df.select($"map").schema.head.dataType

val filterUdf = udf((map:Map[Any,Any]) => map.filter{case (k:Any,v:Any) => mapKeys.contains(k)},colSchema)

df
.select(filterUdf($"map"))
.show()
```

gives

```
+----------+
|  UDF(map)|
+----------+
|[k1 -> v1]|
+----------+
```

This work also for `Row`, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49714640/1138523

Answer (score 2):

you can do a generic factory method for the udf:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def filterUdfFactory[T](mapKeys:Seq[T])(implicit tag:TypeTag[T]) = udf((map:Map[T,T]) => map.filter{case (k,v) => mapKeys.contains(k)})
```

then use as e.g. for Strings:

```
val mapKeys = Seq("k1")

val tt = typeTag[String]
val filterUdf = filterUdfFactory[String](mapKeys)

 val df = Seq(
    Map("k1" -> "v1","k2" -> "v2")
 ).toDF("map")

 df.select(filterUdf($"map"))
.show()
```

gives:

```
+----------+
|  UDF(map)|
+----------+
|[k1 -> v1]|
+----------+
```

Comment: In above code, you are calling "filterUdfFactory" with type "String". But in my case Map's key type and value type is available only at run time.